# Preparing App Preview Videos with Different Resolutions for the App Store

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, app-preview

I want to upload different App Preview videos based on the App Store requirements.
At present, I'm able to export App Preview videos for iPhone 5.5 inch displays for my game product using iMovie.

How can I export App Preview videos for iPhone 6.5 inch - 1080p, iPad Pro 12.9 inch (2nd gen.) and iPad Pro 12.9 inch (3rd gen.) sizes?
What resolutions do I require for these sizes?

At present, I have iMovie and QuickTime Player for exporting or editing videos.

Answer (score 0):

The required sizes are as follows:

```
╔════════════════════════════════════════╦══════════════════════════════════════════╗
║        Device size and platform        ║           Accepted resolutions           ║
╠════════════════════════════════════════╬══════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 6.5" (iPhone XS Max), 6.1" (iPhone XR) ║ 886x1920, 1920x886                       ║
║ 12.9" (iPad Pro (2nd generation))      ║ 1200x1600, 1600x1200, 900x1200, 1200x900 ║
║ 12.9" (iPad Pro (3rd generation))      ║ 1200x1600, 1600x1200                     ║
╚════════════════════════════════════════╩══════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

Source: [App Store Connect Help](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev4e413fcb8)

Comment: my question is - how to export these sizes video ??

Comment: Check out this article: http://jessicastansberry.com/square-video-imovie/ Keep in mind that this is rather a topic for Super User.

Comment: Though above comment link, I can able to export video in all required apple store resolutions. So please update your answer a little bit so I can make it correct and I hope this will become helpful to so many users.

Comment: Especially youtube video exists in that page has solved all problems...